# Play HTML5 video when scrolled to, then play until completion and only play once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to play a video to it's finish once the user scrolls to the point to start the video, then don't play it again.

I'd like for it to 1.) begin playing once they scroll 2.) play video to completion once it begins playing, and 3.) only play once then fallback to the poster image. How can I do this in jQuery?

https://jsfiddle.net/tca0nyqs/ - in this fiddle, it restarts every time the user scrolls.

HTML

```
<video id="about-video" preload="auto" poster="images/about-default.png">
<source src="images/about-work.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
</video>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get media - with autoplay disabled (audio or video)
    var media = $('#about-video').not("[autoplay='autoplay']");
    var tolerancePixel = 300;
    function checkMedia(){
        // Get current browser top and bottom
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + tolerancePixel;
        var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - tolerancePixel;
        media.each(function(index, el) {
          var yTopMedia = $(this).offset().top;
          var yBottomMedia = $(this).height() + yTopMedia;
            if(scrollTop < yBottomMedia && scrollBottom > yTopMedia){ //view explaination in `In brief` section above
              $(this).get(0).play();
            } else {
              $(this).get(0).pause();
            }
          });
        //}
      }
      $(document).on('scroll', checkMedia);
  });
```

Should I somehow use this to check if the video has been played once?

```
  $('#about-video').on('ended',function(){
     // code
  });
```

Comment: use loop attribute

Comment: @Chetan I edited the question to be more clear, but not trying to make it loop. I want it to play only once until completion (even if the user scrolls past so it's no longer in the view).

Comment: UPDATE: I believe I've found a duplicate/working answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33116544/2084793

Answer (score 1):

On Video ended Event make src null [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chetandoke/tca0nyqs/2/).

```
  $('#about-video').on('ended',function(){
     $(this).attr('src','');
   });
```